# How to create server on ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to create a web server application using ASP.Net WebApi 2. The application must parse a HTML page and upload clear data to Azure blob storage.

I've never created Web applications and I don't know how is right worked. Please show me how it is worked and what tehnology to use.

I would like to use ASP.Net WebApi 2, so that I can create an API that parses and uploads data to Azure blob storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out many tutorials there are on the internet.

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-get-started/

http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

Comment: Thanks you @Erez, i'm know how use azure blob storage and asp.net web api or mvc, i'n dont know how to right distribute the load. Where is the logic in creating WEb API? Or use WCF.

Comment: I don't think that load balancing is your problem yet.
Both WCF and WebAPI are web servers (IIS) in the end.